# Do browsers expose events related to the Developer Tools windows?

Tags: javascript, web, dom, browser

Is there a JavaScript API for knowing, for example, when the user clicked the **close** button on the **Developer Tools** window to close it?

Or when they pressed the **F10** key *inside the Developer Tools Debugger* to step through a line of code?

In short, is there an API that exposes **Developer Tools** events?

Comment: Out of interest: what for…?

Comment: Helps me build visitor profile; whether the visitor knows anything about development or is a grandma type visitor. :-)